# Symfony2 RESTApi authentication architecture

Tags: symfony, oauth-2.0, jwt

i'm planning on building Single Page Applications with Polymer and Angular.

As a Symfony2 developer i searched for a bundle that provides me with a json token authentication feature for my RESTApi.

So i found this two bundles:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle

and

https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle

+

https://github.com/gfreeau/GfreeauGetJWTBundle

My main goal here is Log In the user(username + password) without having to redirect him to other page, and of course give him access to protected Api methods

What are the pros and cons of each one ?

Sry for my english.

Comment: A quick "symfony api authentication" search on google will give you official symfony documentation on it: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html

Comment: yes but as described in this bundle https://github.com/gfreeau/GfreeauGetJWTBundle , if you use `stateless: true` in your firewall it will be setting cookies 

" It provides a replacement for the security factory "form_login". "form_login" is designed for use with cookies and will set cookies even when the stateless parameter is true.

The 'switch_user' and 'logout' config options are not supported with this security factory as they rely on cookies. "

Comment: Why would you use `form_login` with stateless REST api?

Comment: You're absolutely right . 

I'm new in this kind of architecture so my mistake.

So , the JWTAuthenticationBundle has no use on symfony 2.7 ?

EDIT: But the goal here is that i send a username and password to an api method and then i obtain a token that authenticates me as the user

here in the symfony docs i already have that token right ? i mean i can't send the user and password and obtain a token

Comment: Ok, I might have misunderstood your question. If you plan to use JWT for authentication, it does make sense since there is more work involved. But if you just need to use plain simple API key authentication, I don't think that there's a need for an additional bundle.

Comment: Great thanks for your help much appreciated :)